# Java exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement?

Tags: java, error-handling, compiler-errors, ioexception

Normally this would be a simple problem I could search on StackExchange, but the other problems I found didn't seem to be the same situation I am in right now.

```
filename = stdin.readLine().trim();
FileWriter fw2 = new FileWriter (filename);
BufferedWriter bw2 = new BufferedWriter (fw2);
PrintWriter outFile2 = new PrintWriter (bw2);
try {
    outFile2.print(office1);
    System.out.print(filename+" was written\n");
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.print(filename+" was not found\n");
}
finally {
    outFile2.close();
}
```

Apparently, the compiler claims that IOException is not thrown by this try block for some reason. Also, another detail to note is office1 is an initialized and instantiated object.
Now here's where this get's tricky. The compiler (before I wrote this code) claimed that this next piece of code was perfectly fine:

```
filename = stdin.readLine().trim();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (filename);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter (bw);
try {
    String input = stdin.readLine().trim();
    System.out.print("Please enter a string to write in the file:\n");
    outFile.print (input+"\n");
    System.out.print(filename+" was written\n");
}
catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println (filename+ " was not found");
}
finally {
    outFile.close();
}
```

Is there any reason why the compiler keeps complaining the upper code doesn't throw IOException yet the lower code does?

Comment: Where do you think an `IOException` can be thrown in your snippets and why do you think so?

Comment: Perhaps `outFile.print(String)` doesn't throw an `IOException` while `stdin.readLine()` does?

Comment: @NiekHaarman Doesn't outFile.print(String) actually print a String to some form of a file, thus being supposed to throw IOException? Apparently it doesn't throw IOException, but somehow writes to the file? Sorry, I just don't understand some of this since my instructor at college didn't explain this thoroughly to us.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There are two lines of code in the try block, and one of them is a `System.out.println()`. Using my incredible powers of deduction, I guess the OP thinks `PrintWriter.print()` should throw an IOException, which is a reasonable thing considering that most file writers would throw one (this one doesn't, but most do).

Comment: Whether or not it throws an `IOException` is mostly a design choice of the person who wrote the method or class. While most writers _do_ throw an `IOException` when something goes wrong, apparently this one doesn't. You will have to poll the instance yourself if you want to see if something went wrong. See also [rgettman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29268120/675383).

Comment: @GameAnalysis See the [Javadoc.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) That class's methods don't throw `IOExceptions,` they swallows them: you are expected to call `checkError()`, which nobody ever does. If the file is critical, use a `BufferedWriter` around a `FileWriter`.

Comment: @NiekHaarman The instructor wants us to actually print a serialized object to a file, but didn't specify on how to actually serialize it. She claims that all I needed to do was implements Serializable on the class you want to serialize (In this case, the PostOffice class object named office1).The only problem now that I am facing is that using the writeObject() method won't work in the main method that creates the PostOffice object.

Comment: @GameAnalysis In that case (a) you are misquoting the instructor and (b) you're barking up the wrong tree altogether. She almost certainly said to '*write*' to a file, not 'print', for which you use `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject().` "Won't work' is not a problem description.

Comment: @EJP So ObjectOutputStream.writeObject() seems to be a non-static method referenced in a static context. Would there be any way to possibly use it in a static context? Edit: I just saw why I got the error in this comment. The part I'm confused on is how I can use writeObject() in the main method.

Comment: @GameAnalysis Again, see the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `outfile2` is a `PrintWriter`.  Somewhat surprisingly, [`PrintWriter` methods don't throw exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

> Methods in this class never throw I/O exceptions, although some of its constructors may. The client may inquire as to whether any errors have occurred by invoking checkError().

That explains why your first code doesn't throw `IOException`.

In your second code, you add a call to `readLine()`, probably from a `BufferedReader`, that does throw `IOException`.

Comment: Apparently I'm doing the wrong thing entirely. I was told to use BufferedWriter and insert it into a PrintWriter to write a serialized object into a file. I'm guessing there is a different thing I should be doing here then?